# I'm seeing gyms in Pokémon Go with pokémon that have ridiculous CP numbers, and I have no clue what they are

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm a relatively new player to Pokémon Go, but I do know the basics. That being said, I was out for a drive earlier today when I stumbled across a gym at a church with a pokémon that had a CP of over 48,000! Later, I found another gym with another 48,000 CP pokémon in it, and that's when I started wondering if I was missing something.

I researched in and out about gyms, but I was unable to find anything about these high-level CP pokémon. What are these high-CP pokémon?

Comment: If you're in a major metro area, there are likely Discord servers where the other players hang out and organize Raid Groups for the Legendary (5 ***** ) raids and/or Mega raids.  The Silph Road has a list of them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

These are probably raids, and not a Pokemon that are put there by other players for defending the gyms. You can identify the difference by a timer below the raid boss. Also, if you click on the gym, a special short taunt/attack video is shown of the raid boss, which is not there in case there is a raid boss. You will also end up in a raid lobby, instead of an overview of the defending Pokemon.

Comment: Also important to know, each of them got a rating. 1 or 2 might be possible alone, but when its a 5 rated, you will need a team. Also: You will know its a raid when the pokemon is big on top of the gym. instead of having to click in to see it.

Comment: @Fredy31 FYI, there are only odd-numbered levels now (1,3,5).  1 is soloable by anyone L30+, 3 is soloable in most cases by L40+ or L30 with optimal counters.

Comment: didnt know they removed the 2 and 4 star raid.